# Clear form after submit and success message

Tags: php, html

I made my own contact form and it is sending mails but i want it to clear after succesfully submit and to show message (pop up window can be good) with success sending. here is my code and i don't know what to do, it ried few things but nothing work.

```
<form id="contact-form" class="wniosek" action="wyslijWniosek.php"  method="POST">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <label class="firma rel col-sm-12">
            <span class="inp">
                <input name="firma" type="text" placeholder="Nazwa Firmy" class="col-sm-12">
            </span>
        </label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
        <label class="name rel col-sm-12">
            <span class="inp">
                <input name="name" type="text" placeholder="Imię i nazwisko" class="col-sm-12">
            </span>
        </label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
        <label class="phone rel col-sm-12">
            <span class="inp">
                <input name="phone" type="text" placeholder="Telefon" class="col-sm-12">
            </span>
        </label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
        <label class="email rel col-sm-12">
            <span class="inp">
                <input name="email" type="text" placeholder="E-mail" class="col-sm-12">
            </span>
        </label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
        <label class="kwota rel col-sm-12">
            <span class="inp">
                <input name="kwota" type="text" placeholder="Prognozowana Kwota" class="col-sm-12">
            </span>
        </label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
        <label class="wnio col-sm-12">
                <select name="wnio" style="width:100%;"> 
                    <option value="Kredyt Firmowy">Kredyt Firmowy</option>
                    <option value="Kredyt Gotówkowy">Kredyt Gotówkowy</option>
                    <option value="Kredyt Obrotowy">Kredyt Obrotowy</option>
                    <option value="Pożyczka Hipoteczna">Pożyczka Hipoteczna</option>
                    <option value="Kredyt Hipoteczny">Kredyt Hipoteczny</option>
                    <option value="Kredyt Konsolidacyjny">Kredyt Konsolidacyjny</option>
                    <option value="Kredyt Inwestycyjny">Kredyt Inwestycyjny</option>
                    <option value="Kredyt Samochodowy">Kredyt Samochodowy</option>
                    <option value="Leasing">Leasing</option>
                </select>
        </label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-12">
        <label class="message rel col-sm-12">
            <span class="text_a">
                <textarea name="message" class="col-sm-12" placeholder="Wiadomość" style="height:300px;"></textarea>
            </span>
        </label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div class="buttons-wrapper"><input class="button2 btn btn-white" type="submit" value="Wyślij"><input class="button2 btn btn-white" type="reset" value="Wyczyść">
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

php:

```
<?php
$firma = $_POST['firma'];
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$wnio = $_POST['wnio'];
$kwota = $_POST['kwota'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$formcontent=" Nazwa Firmy: $firma \n Imie i Nazwisko: $name \n Email: $email \n Telefon: $phone \n Wniosek: $wnio \n Prognozowana Kwota: $kwota \n Wiadomość: $message";
$recipient = "<mymailhere>";
$subject = "Formularz Kontaktowy";
$mailheader = "From: $email";
mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader);
exit();//Remove this after debugging done
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

> Use this simple code

```
mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader);
header("location:wniosek.php?form=success");
```

And in you `wniosek.php` page use this code to display the status

```
<?php if($_GET['form']=="success") { echo "Registered Successfully"; } ?>
```

Comment: So i should make a form.php file? My contact form is in wniosek.html page

Comment: now i have something like that and its not working header("location:wniosek.html?form=success");

Comment: How could you use php in html file... use this in `.php` file instead of `.html`

Comment: Ok so now i have wniosek.pgp(where i have contact form), in send.php i added header("location:wniosek.php?form=success"); and in my wniosek.php header i added: <?php if($_GET['contact-form']=="success") { echo "Registered Sucessfully";}?>

Comment: still message is sending, form is not clearing, no message

Comment: I think you made some mistake.. Check once again... Because its like you visiting newly a page... form data won't stay if u do like that...

Comment: So once again i did something like that: i did put this in send.php after mail header("location:wniosek.php?form=success"); and between <head> i put this <?php if($_GET['form']=="success") { echo "Registered Successfully";}?> and nothing happend, message is sending but form is not clearing and no message

Comment: `header("location:wniosek.php?form=success");` **Make sure you put before `exsit()`**. And exsit() do not need try to remove it...

Comment: what about your `wniosek.php?` and what you are getting in `url`(address bar)??

Comment: This is my wniosek.php: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=7BYNZHqe and in url i get <site>/wniosek.php and i think it should be <site>/wniosek.php?form=success

Comment: Yes it should be like `<site>/wniosek.php?form=success `

Comment: so what now? it looks like i did anything good and it's ot working

Comment: Because in form page form action `wyslijWniosek.php` and then how it will work in `send.php` file code? try to put redirect in `wyslijWniosek.php` file....

Comment: well wyslijWniosek.php is not using (i dont know why it automatically using assets/php/send.php) so im editing send.php file

Comment: I don't understand what you are telling. Because when you submit form it  directly sends to `wyslijWniosek.php` because of using form action?

Comment: It is working right now i added onsubmit="this.submit();return false;" with your changes in wyslijWniosek.php and the message is working now :)

Answer (score 0):

A fast solution with clearing the form would be

```
<form id="contact-form" class="wniosek" action="wyslijWniosek.php"  method="POST" onsubmit="this.submit(); this.reset(); return false;">
```

**EDIT:**
Ignore the first answer. Delete`action` attribute and add this to bottom of page

```
<script>
function submitForm() {
    $.ajax({type:'POST', url: 'wyslijWniosek.php', data:$('#contact-form').serialize(), success: function(response) {
        $('#contact-form').reset();
        alert("Success!");
    }});

    return false;
}
</script>
```

Comment: it is cleaning form and sending message but it is sending an empty message (it looks like it sending after reset)

Comment: I edited the answer. Now the form is reseted after data is sent to php.
You can add some custom messages in php if the data is not valid and return it in a message. Using jquery is better then using traditional form submission.

Comment: it is refreshing (for a second i could see message under email input "Email must be valid") and message is not sending