# Replacing HTML form with success message after submit, form sends mail using separate php file

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

I have an html contact form which is built into index.html, and then I have a mail.php file that sends a mail and also uses some Javascript. When I fill in form and submit, I have coded it to send the mail and then it pops up with a success message box and then redirects back to index.html.

What I would like is for the form to be replaced with the success message, to avoid a page refresh and also to avoid the popup message box.

form from index.html:

```
<form  action="mail.php" method="POST">
    <div class="row uniform">
    <div class="6u 12u$(xsmall)">
        <input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="" placeholder="Name" />
    </div>
    <div class="6u$ 12u$(xsmall)">
        <input type="email" name="email" id="email" value="" placeholder="Email" />
    </div>
    <div class="12u$">
        <!--<div class="select-wrapper">

        </div>-->
    </div>
    <div class="12u$">
        <textarea name="message" id="message" placeholder="Enter your message" rows="6"></textarea>
    </div>
        <center><div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey=""></div></center>
    <div class="12u$">
        <ul class="actions">
        <li><input type="submit" value="Send Message" class="special" /></li>
        <li><input type="reset" value="Reset" /></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

php file, email address and recaptcha token removed for obvious reasons:

```
<?php $name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$formcontent = "From: $name \n email: $email \n Message: $message";
$recipient = 'email address here';
$subject = 'Message from Website';
$mailheader = "From: $email \r\n";
$captcha;
{
  if(isset($_POST['g-recaptcha-response']))
    {
      $captcha=$_POST['g-recaptcha-response'];
    }
  if(!$captcha)
    {
      echo '<script language="javascript">';
      echo 'alert("Please check the Captcha")';
      echo '</script>';
      exit;  
    }
  $response=file_get_contents("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=&response=".$captcha."&remoteip=".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
  if($response.success==false)
  {
    echo '<h2>Please do not try and spam here.</h2>';
  }else
  {
mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader) or die("Error!");
echo '<script language="javascript">';
echo 'alert("Your Message successfully sent, we will get back to you ASAP.");';
echo 'window.location.href="index.html";';
echo '</script>';
  }
} ?>
```

This is a topic that I have actually looked at:

[Clear form after submit and success message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30935579/clear-form-after-submit-and-success-message)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Best way to do all your stuff is to use ajax. Include jquery in your html.

Put your form inside a wrapper div

```
<div class="something">
<!-- your form here -->
</div>
```

Submit your form through ajax, instead of using basic form submission

```
//"idform" is the id of the form
$("#idForm").submit(function() {

    var url = "path/to/your/script.php"; // the script where you handle the form input.

    $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: url,
           // serialize your form's elements.
           data: $("#idForm").serialize(), 
           success: function(data)
           {
               // "something" is the class of your form wrapper
               $('.something').html(data);
           }
         });
    // avoid to execute the actual submit of the form.
    return false;
});
```

And last thing you need to change is in your php code

keep only one echo for success

```
echo "Your Message successfully sent, we will get back to you ASAP.";
```

Comment: just FYI : `data.message` will be undefined, `data` itself will be a string — `"Your Message successfully sent, we will get back to you ASAP."`

Comment: oops.. I thought I'm returning a formatted json... Thanks, I'll update my answer.

Comment: @SumitPandey I'm interested in trying your answer, I implemented the answer submitted by hunijkah but there is an error with the error checking, I have been looking at it to see what the issue is, but I'm new to Ajax and jquery. My php file already had all of the error checking in so I thought the php file would still handle that. Would your answer solve my solution? I am so close to having this work but the error checking is literally the only bump in the road, if the form is filled in correctly it works perfectly.

Comment: @Troy: hey, if you want to use hunijkah method... just one change.. array_push is a function not a variable. so you have to change $array_push to array_push in mail.php

Comment: @SumitPandey I actually tried your method now and it works perfectly, just the way that I want. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish this using jQuery and Ajax form submit.

First, include jquery in your head element

```
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

Next, give your form an id

```
<form  id='mail_form' action="mail.php" method="POST">
```

Add a span somewhere with the id='error'

```
<span id='error' style='color:red; font-weight:bold;'></span>
```

Adjust the mail.php to the following:

```
<?php 
$success = true;
$errors = array();

$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$formcontent = "From: $name \n email: $email \n Message: $message";
$recipient = 'email address here';
$subject = 'Message from Website';
$mailheader = "From: $email \r\n";
$captcha = false;

  if(isset($_POST['g-recaptcha-response']))
  {
      $captcha=$_POST['g-recaptcha-response'];
  }
  if(!$captcha)
  {
      $success = false;
      array_push($errors, "Please check the captcha");
  }
  $response=file_get_contents("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=&response=".$captcha."&remoteip=".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
  if($response.success==false)
  {
    $success = false;
    array_push($errors, "Please do not try and spam here.");

  }

if ($success)
{
    mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader) or die("Error!");
}

$output_array = array("success" => $success, "errors" => $errors);
echo json_encode($output_array);
 ?>
```

Then, at the bottom of your page add

```
<script>
$('#mail_form').on('submit', function(){
    var dataIn = $(this).serialize(); //serialize turns the form data into a string that can be passed to mail.php. Try doing alert(dataIn); to see what it holds.
    $.post( "./mail.php", dataIn )
        .done(function( dataOut )
        {
        //dataOut holds the response from mail.php. The response would be any html mail.php outputs. I typically echo out json encoded arrays as responses that you can parse here in the jQuery.
        var myArray = JSON.parse(dataOut );
        if (myArray['success'] == true) //Check if it was successfull.
            {
             $("#mail_form").html("Congrats! We just e-mailed you!");
            }
        else //there were errors
           { 
           $('#error').html(""); //Clear error span

            $.each(myArray['errors'], function(i){ 
            $('#error').append(myArray['errors'][i] + "<br>");
           }
        });
return false; //Make sure you do this or it will submit the form and redirect
});
</script>
```

Comment: So I have used your solution, and it does work. however, none of my error checking works anymore, i.e. I fill in just the name and a message without filling email or ticking the recaptcha, and it still comes with a success message, what should I do to make sure that i still get the same error checking that I get like I used to with my php file?

Comment: @Troy change done to : `success`, and add a `.fail` you will be able to output accordingly depending on server response. http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: @Troy I just updated my answer to include error checking the way I explained in a comment with JSON arrays

Comment: @hunijkah so I made all the changes you said, when i fill in all of the fields, and tick the captcha, the message comes up correctly and then i receive the mail. I then tried leaving the email part blank and ticking the captcha and it came up with fatal error: "Function name must be a string in /mail.php on line 21" So I guess it isn't capturing the errors correctly, in another case, I left the captcha unticked and it displayed the success message, but it didn't actually send the email. Sorry for needing to be spoonfed all of this, I'm more of a C# programmer but I am learning from all this.

Comment: @hunijkah: hey, array_push is a function not a variable. so you have to change $array_push to array_push in mail.php

Answer (score 1):

First of all you should use AJAX call to submit the form. If you insist on using pure JS the script would look like this (written in 5 seconds - probably needs some adjusting):

```
<script>

document.forms['yourForm'].onsubmit = function(form) { // you have to add 'name' attribute to the form and replace 'yourForm' with it
    var data = ... //here you have to get all the values from form elements and store them in data object. to make less changes to the script use the elements' names as object names
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {
        var xhReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else
    {
        var xhReq = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }


    var method= 'POST')
    var async = false; //you can actually set true here, it doesn't matter much in this case
    var url = 'mail.php';
    xhReq.open(method, url, async);
    xhReq.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xhReq.setRequestHeader("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest");
    xhReq.send(data);



    document.getElementById("form's parent's ID goes here").innerHTML = "new content"


    return false;
}
</script>
```

Than you have to remove all echos from php file as it wouldn't be shown anyway. You can also add some more sophistication to this script e.g. check if the mail function worked correctly (by returning something in php file and checking the AJAX response in JS) or to catch the captcha errors. It would also be extremely easier to achieve in jQuery if you're willing to go down that road.

Comment: plus 1 for native xhr req.