# Impossible to obtain a PHP variable in HTML file via AJAX/Jquery

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I am really beginning in PHP/AJAX/Jquery. And I tried the hunijkah's code from this page [Replacing HTML form with success message after submit, form sends mail using separate php file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33097135/replacing-html-form-with-success-message-after-submit-form-sends-mail-using-sep#) and the PHP file gave back: `{"success":true,"errors":[]}` on a blank page replacing the current page. And I received emails. So I assume that contact.php works.
 I wonder how to get back 'success' in my HTML file and write an answer below the form in my current page after the successful operation.
Here the form, I used:

```
<form action="contact.php" method="post" id="mail_form">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Coordonnées personnelles :</legend>
    <p><input class="w3-input w3-padding-16 w3-border" type="text" placeholder="Prénom *" required name="firstname" maxlength="50"></p>
    <p><input class="w3-input w3-padding-16 w3-border" type="text" placeholder="Nom *" required name="lastname" maxlength="50"></p>
    <p><input class="w3-input w3-padding-16 w3-border" type="email" placeholder="Email *" required name="email"></p>
    <p><input class="w3-input w3-padding-16 w3-border" type="tel" placeholder="+681 12 34 56 *" required name="usrtel"></p>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Informations :</legend>
    <p><input class="w3-input w3-padding-16 w3-border" type="number" placeholder="Combien de personne(s) *" required name="people" min="1" max="100"></p>
    <p><input class="w3-input w3-padding-16 w3-border" type="text" placeholder="Message \ Besoins particuliers *" required name="message"></p>
  </fieldset>
  <p>* Champs obligatoires</p>
  <br>
  <div class="g-recaptcha" data-theme="dark" data-sitekey="6LdMKTcUAAAAABNdlU76EOu6W3Wv61T7uKGM9HwB"></div>
  <p>Souhaitez-vous une copie de votre message ? 
  <input type="radio" id="rep_oui" name="copie" value="oui" checked><label for="rep_oui">Oui</label>
  <input type="radio" id="rep_non" name="copie" value="non"><label for="rep_non">Non</label></p>
  <p id="error" class="w3-red w3-xlarge w3-center"></p>
  <p><button class="w3-button w3-light-grey w3-block" type="submit" name="submit">ENVOYER LE MESSAGE</button></p>
  <p><button class="w3-button w3-light-grey w3-block" type="reset">EFFACER</button></p>
</form>
```

In HTML file, I put this script between the head tags :

```
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script> // 2.1.3 -> 3.2.1
```

And this script at the bottom of my file:

```
<script>
  $('#mail_form').on('submit', function(event)
  {
    event.preventDefault();
    var dataIn = $(this).serialize(); //serialize turns the form data into a string that can be passed to contact.php. Try doing alert(dataIn); to see what it holds.
    $.post( "./contact.php" , dataIn )
    .done(function( dataOut )
    {
      //dataOut holds the response from contact.php. The response would be any html mail.php outputs. I typically echo out json encoded arrays as responses that you can parse here in the jQuery.
      var finalArray = JASON.parse ( dataOut );
      if ((finalArray['success'] == true) && (finalArray['error1'] == false) && (finalArray['error2'] == false))//Check if it was successfull.
      {  
        $("#mail_form").html("<p class='w3-xxlarge w3-center w3-tag'><strong>Votre message a bien été envoyé !</strong></p>");
      }
      else //there were errors
      {
        if (finalArray['error1'] == true)
        {
          // message not sent
          $('#error').html("<p class='w3-xxlarge w3-center w3-tag'><strong>L'envoi du mail a échoué, veuillez réessayer, s'il vous plaît.</strong></p>");
        }
        else if (finalArray['error2'] == true)
        {
          // one of 7 variables (at least) is empty ...
          $('#error').html("<p class='w3-xxlarge w3-center w3-tag'><strong>Vérifiez que tous les champs soient bien remplis et que l'email soit sans erreur.</strong></p>");
        }
        else
        {
          // recaptcha is false
          $('#error').html("<p class='w3-xxlarge w3-center w3-tag'><strong>Problème d'authentification par le Recaptcha</strong></p>");
        };
      };
    });
      return false; //Make sure you do this or it will submit the form and redirect
  });
</script>
```

I can't see my mistake(s). It's exactly the same code and I wonder what's wrong. Maybe someone can help me because after dayS I've hit a brick wall.
Can I use a test in the HTML file to be sure that success variable is passed by the PHP file ?

PS : PHP file

```
<?php

    $success = true;
    $error1 = false;
    $error2 = false;

     // ReCAPTCHA
     // grab recaptcha library
     require_once "recaptchalib.php";

     // foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
     // echo '<p><strong>' . $key.':</strong> '.$value.'</p>';
     // }

     // your secret key
     $secret = "***_***";

     // empty response
     $response = null;

     // check secret key
     $reCaptcha = new ReCaptcha($secret);

     // if submitted check response
     if ($_POST["g-recaptcha-response"]) {
          $response = $reCaptcha->verifyResponse(
          $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"],
          $_POST["g-recaptcha-response"]
          );
     }

/*
    ********************************************************************************************
    CONFIGURATION
    ********************************************************************************************
*/

// destinataire est votre adresse mail. Pour envoyer à plusieurs à la fois, séparez-les par une virgule
$destinataire = '***@***.**,***@***.**';

// copie ? (envoie une copie au visiteur)
// $copie = 'oui';

// objet du message
$objet = 'Contact depuis le site ***';

// Action du formulaire (si votre page a des paramètres dans l'URL)
// si cette page est index.php?page=contact alors mettez index.php?page=contact
// sinon, laissez vide
$form_action = '';

/*
    ********************************************************************************************
    FIN DE LA CONFIGURATION
    ********************************************************************************************
*/

/*
 * cette fonction sert à nettoyer et enregistrer un texte
 */
function Rec($text)
{
    $text = htmlspecialchars(trim($text), ENT_QUOTES);
    if (1 === get_magic_quotes_gpc())
    {
        $text = stripslashes($text);
    }

    $text = nl2br($text);
    return $text;
};

/*
 * Cette fonction sert à vérifier la syntaxe d'un email
 */
function IsEmail($email)
{
    $value = preg_match('/^(?:[\w\!\#\$\%\&\'\*\+\-\/\=\?\^\`\{\|\}\~]+\.)*[\w\!\#\$\%\&\'\*\+\-\/\=\?\^\`\{\|\}\~]+@(?:(?:(?:[a-zA-Z0-9_](?:[a-zA-Z0-9_\-](?!\.)){0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9_-]?\.)+[a-zA-Z0-9_](?:[a-zA-Z0-9_\-](?!$)){0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9_]?)|(?:\[(?:(?:[01]?\d{1,2}|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.){3}(?:[01]?\d{1,2}|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\]))$/', $email);
    return (($value === 0) || ($value === false)) ? false : true;
}


// formulaire envoyé, on récupère tous les champs.
    $firstnameint     = (isset($_POST['firstname']))     ? Rec($_POST['firstname'])        : '';
    $lastnameint      = (isset($_POST['lastname']))      ? Rec($_POST['lastname'])         : '';
    $email            = (isset($_POST['email']))         ? Rec($_POST['email'])            : '';
    $usrtelint        = (isset($_POST['usrtel']))        ? Rec($_POST['usrtel'])           : '';
    $people           = (isset($_POST['people']))        ? Rec($_POST['people'])           : '';
    $messageint       = (isset($_POST['message']))       ? Rec($_POST['message'])          : '';
    $copieint         = (isset($_POST['copie']))         ? Rec($_POST['copie'])            : '';

// traitement du numéro de téléphone et aux variables
    $firstname = htmlspecialchars($firstnameint);
    $lastname = htmlspecialchars($lastnameint);
    $usrtel = htmlspecialchars($usrtelint);
    $message = htmlspecialchars($messageint);
    $copie = htmlspecialchars($copieint);

// traitement du nombre de convives
    $people = sprintf("%d",$_POST['people']); // ici le nombre sera un entier
    $people = abs($people); // $people sera positif ou nul = valeur absolue (évite les âges négatifs !)
    $people = intval($people); // renvoie aussi une valeur entière
    if (is_numeric($people)) // n'effectue que si $people est numérique
    {   
    } else {
        $people='0';
    }
    if ($people >= 1 && $people <= 100) // n'effectue que si $usrtel est borné
    {
    } else {
        $people='0';
    }

// On va vérifier les variables et l'email ...
     $email = (IsEmail($email)) ? $email : ''; // soit l'email est vide si erroné, soit il vaut l'email entré

if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    if ($response != null && $response->success)
    {    
        if (($firstname != '') && ($lastname != '') && ($email != '') && ($usrtel != '') && ($people != '') && ($message != '') && ($copie != ''))
        {
            // les 6 variables sont remplies, on génère puis envoie le mail
            $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\n";
            $headers .= 'From:'.$firstname.' '.$lastname.' <'.$email.'>' . "\n" .
            $headers .= 'Reply-To:'.$email. "\n" .
            $headers .= 'Content-Type: text/html; charset="utf-8"; DelSp="Yes"; format=flowed '."\n" .
            $headers .= 'X-Mailer:PHP/'.phpversion().
            $headers .= 'Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit'." \r\n" ;

            // envoyer une copie au visiteur ?
            if ($copie == 'oui')
            {
                $cible = $destinataire.';'.$email;
            }
            else
            {
                $cible = $destinataire;
            };

            // Remplacement de certains caractères spéciaux
            $message = str_replace("&#039;","'",$message);
            $message = str_replace("&#8217;","'",$message);
            $message = str_replace("&quot;",'"',$message);
            $message = str_replace('<br>','',$message);
            $message = str_replace('<br />','',$message);
            $message = str_replace("&lt;","<",$message);
            $message = str_replace("&gt;",">",$message);
            $message = str_replace("&amp;","&",$message);

            // formatage du corps de l'email
            $msg = '<div style="width: 100%; text-align: left; color: #00002b; font-weight: bold"> Message de '.$firstname.' '.
            $lastname.'<br />E-mail : '.$email.' et numéro de téléphone : '.$usrtel.'<br /> nombre de personne(s) : '.$people.
            '<br /> Message : '.$message.'</div>';

            // Envoi du mail
            $num_emails = 0;
            $tmp = explode(';', $cible);          
            foreach($tmp as $email_destinataire)
            {
                if (mail($email_destinataire, $objet, $msg, $headers))
                $num_emails++;
            }

            if ((($copie == 'oui') && ($num_emails == 2)) || (($copie == 'non') && ($num_emails == 1)))
            {
                // message sent
                // Votre message a bien été envoyé !
            }
            else
            {
                // message not sent
                // L'envoi du mail a échoué, veuillez réessayer, s'il vous plaît
                $error1 = true;
            };               
        }
        else
        {
            // one of 7 variables (at least) is empty ...
            // Vérifiez que tous les champs soient bien remplis et que l'email soit sans erreur
            $error2 = true;
        };                
    }
    else
    {
        // recaptcha is false
        // Problème d'authentification par le Recaptcha
        $success = false;
    };
}; // fin du if (!isset($_POST['envoi']))

        $array['success'] = $success;
        $array['error1'] = $error1;
        $array['error2'] = $error2;
        $finalArray=json_encode($array);
        echo $finalArray;
?>
```

Comment: Are there any errors in the Javascript console?

Comment: I'll bet anything that `contact.php` is outputting some HTML in addition to the JSON.

Comment: Nothing is impossible!

Comment: Have you taken the basic debugging steps? Check the console output. Check what the request returns in the network tab of the inspector. Add `console.log` calls all over with the data as it is processed. Oh gosh, you could even use breakpoints and inspect data as you step through the code. Can you imagine that?

Comment: I'd bet you're still submitting the form, change that to `$('#mail_form').on('submit', function(event) {  event.preventDefault();`

Comment: @ Barmar after fixing missing bracket, the Javascript returns now: _SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected end of data at line 2 column 1 of the JSON data_

Comment: Read my edit in my comment, i seen now your PHP now we know there is the error....Bye and good days

Answer (score 1):

The code you wrote is missing a ) bracket....and you must see in console.log in browser what return after JSON.parse...i attach the code with the missing bracket.
PS:For Jquery, now it's on 3.2 version...i suggest to upgrade at the current version instead that continue to use version 2, but this doesn't affect your code.

```
          $('#mail_form').on('submit', function()
          {
            var dataIn = $(this).serialize(); //serialize turns the form data into a string that can be passed to contact.php. Try doing alert(dataIn); to see what it holds.
            $.post("./contact.php", dataIn )
            .done(function( dataOut )
            {
              //dataOut holds the response from contact.php. The response would be any html mail.php outputs. I typically echo out json encoded arrays as responses that you can parse here in the jQuery.
              var myArray = JSON.parse(dataOut);
              console.log(myArray);
              if (myArray['success'] == true) //Check if it was successfull.
              {
                $("#mail_form").html("Congrats! We just e-mailed you!");
              }
              else //there were errors
              { 
                $('#error').html(""); //Clear error span
                $.each(myArray['errors'], function(i)
                { 
                  $('#error').append(myArray['errors'][i] + "<br>");
                });//------->HERE WAS MISSING A ); 
              };
            });
              return false; //Make sure you do this or it will submit the form and redirect
          });
```

Hy Falakiko i answer you here because i put an example, your error it's probabily a wrong codification of the json array that php send to client javascript i write what i usually do to manage json data, inside a fecth of a query i insert a "contatore"(1,2,3,etc...) and stored rows inside an array $risultatiArray[] = array(.....) out of the loop i defined the array response json with the respective KEYS success, the key records and the key totaleRisultati that is the total contatore..after json_encode response...add also /n /r replaced with space but can be ininfluent.

```
            while ($sql->fetch()){
                ++$contatore;
                $risultatiArray[] = array('recid'  => trim($contatore),
                                          'rowid' => $id,
                                          'utente' => trim($Utente),
                                          'mese'   => trim($Mese),
                                          'orePermesso' => trim($OrePermesso));

            }
            $response['status'] = 'success';
            $response['records'] = $risultatiArray;
            $response['totaleRisultati'] = $contatore;
            $response = json_encode($response);
            $response = str_replace("\n", "", $response);
            $response = str_replace("\r", "", $response); 
            print $response;
```

And the json looks like this:

```
  {"status":"success","records":[{"recid":"1","rowid":9,"utente":"Andrea","mese":"Aprile","orePermesso":"8"},{"recid":"2","rowid":8,"utente":"andrea","mese":"Gennaio","orePermesso":"8"}],"totaleRisultati":2}
```

So your code using success and error like an array, because i suppose from your code that errors is an array($.each(myArray['errors'])) could be :

```
       $arrayErrori[] = array('1'=>'error1','2'=>'error2');
       $array['succes'] = true;
       $array['errors'] = $arrayErrori;
       $finalArray=json_encode($array);
       print $finalArray;
```

and the json will look like this....but keep in mind that "true" could be recognize like a string, must see this on road...

```
    {"succes":true,"errors":[{"1":"error1","2":"error2"}]}
```

Ok now I'VE SEEN your php your error is that you are parsing an object that was just parsed in the server side, your json is correct.The error is here:

```
       var myArray = JSON.parse( dataOut );
```

the dataOut is just in json you don't need to reparse. So

```
            var myArray = dataOut //Don't need to reparse again
```

an example of an ajax call and the php

```
        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "MNYLINKPHPTOCALL JSON",
          dataType: "JSON",
          data:{},
          success:function(data){   
                console.log(data);  
                console.log(data.success);
                console.log(data.errors);
                console.log(data.errors[0]);
                console.log(data.errors[1]);
          },
          error:function(data){
            alert('Chiamata Fallita');
          }
        });
```

AND THE JSON FROM THE PHP

```
$risultatiErrors= array("prova","prova2");      
$output_array['success'] = true;
$output_array['errors'] = $risultatiErrors;
$final = json_encode($output_array);//<---------yOU ARE JUST ENCODING HERE
echo $final;
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I fixed the missing braket and the version of Jquery. I found the console.log and now it returns : _SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected end of data at line 2 column 1 of the JSON data_. I tried to use (https://jsonlint.com/) but I don't know how to use it properly.

Comment: Thanks to you, I've made some progress. I modified html and php file that I remplaced in my original message. Your explanations are very clear, I need just time to digest them :D. <br> Also I saw my Html page modified that I wanted (the form disappear and a confirm message appear instead) but no more email were sent.

Comment: After I sent a message without check the Recaptcha, the html page hasn't be anymore modified. Now, I am receiving emails but after submitted I arrive on this page (mysite/contact.php) with _{"success":true,"errors":[{"error1":"","error2":""}]}_ message. For now, I'll try to understand and improve my code with the Ajax function. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: I've posted my last php file and script JSON and I can't submit anymore, I think because I missed something in the HTML file. I am returning to your Ajax function. Thanks again Spizzi for all your contributions.